# content type octet stream and handling it on backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, encoding

I am uploading pdf image via form on frontend then send it to backend and save it there. I am using in front FormData object to store the image. Saving it to backend sets the content type header to `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`. Saving it with nodejs works as follows:

```
fs.writeFile(this.TMP_FILE, fileBinary, 'binary', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    reject(new TechError('File upload error_stage1'));
  }
  resolve();
})
```

It is working code, but I don't fully understand why, because when you log the payload into the console you get something like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryzeBEQrZzkzny72uz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="5b929145ca1f9c2394e4b2e9-1PDF.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

------WebKitFormBoundarysAZurrUo3QA6bEO7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1PDF.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

%âãÏÓ1.3
                       O 9/E 3524/N 1/T 7656/H [ 451 137]>>
<</DecodeParms<</Columns 4/Predictor 12>>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<4DC91A1875A6D707AEC203BB021C93A0><F6C92B368A8A13408457A1D395A37EB9>]/Index[7 21]/Info 6 0 R/Length 52/Prev 7657/Root 8 0 R/Size 28/Type/XRef/
W[1 2 1]>>stream
hÞbbd``b`²╔
```

where as with **binary** data i would expect it to be an array of bits something like `[11110101010010110101010101...]`. Why is this working?

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` will interpret binary data (the stream of 1 and 0) as text. Pdf are binary files but they contain a lot of text, that's why you see a lot of recognizable characters in there, however there is a lot of gibberish as well since a lot of binary data that serves different purposes inside the pdf will be printed as text by `console.log`

You will never see an output of `11110101010010110101010101...` when printing a binary object with `console.log`.